# Query based on 1 or multiple fields filled in

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

I'm sure this is super easy but I am drawing a blank. I have 5 textboxes to be used for searching. if TextBox1 is filled in then populate GridView1, TextBox2 for GridView2, etc. Then I have 4 more GridViews that can be populated if just TextBox1 or just TextBox2 are filled but also populates if both are filled. And another GridView that will populate based on 1 or 3 of the TextBoxes being filled.

Is there a way other than Switch or 500 If scenarios to code for populating a GridView based on 1 to 3 search fields filled in?

Comment: you should be a bit more specific, and show an example of sql code and/or asp.net code.

Comment: @Nino ok let's just look at one GridView. 5 search boxes: CompanyID, CustomerNumber, LocationID, MarketerNumber, and MeterNumber. This GridView can populate if CustomerNumber is the only box filled, or LocationID, or MarketerNumber. It can also be populated if CustomerNumber AND LocationID, or CustomerNumber AND MarketerNumber, or LocationID AND MarketerNumber. So in a nutshell, 7 different datasets depending on number of search/filter's filled in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with LINQ. Started with a base dataset, then filtered it down base on if next TextBox was empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I usually define a specific search query with multiple input parameters, which checks whether every parameter has value or not.

For example

```
-- This part only if you use ODBC connection, it you use SQL Client connection you don't need it
declare @CompanyID int
declare @CustomerNumber int
declare @LocationID int
declare @AnotherFilter varchar(100)

SELECT @CompanyID=?, @CustomerNumber=?, @LocationID=?, @AnotherFilter=?

-- End ODBC specific

SELECT *
FROM Your_table
WHERE
(COMPANY_ID=@CompanyID OR @CompanyID=0)
AND
(CUSTOMER_NUMBER=@CustomerNumber OR @CustomerNumber=0)
AND 
(LOCATION_ID=@LocationID OR @LocationID=0)
AND
(ANOTHER_FIELD=@AnotherFilter OR @AnotherFilter='')
```

You can put this in your SQLDataSource or ObjectDataSource for the GridView(s)

Comment: this is with the assumption they fill out each textbox. Say they don't fill in LocationTextBox, then the AND of the WHERE clause will return nothing.

Comment: You link the GridView with an ObjectDataSource, in this you reference a method where you test the parameters and pass default values to tue query